# Charts in SSRS are pixelated/blurry when in subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I've a report that uses a sub-report that contains a line graph.

This is in report manager as sub-report:

[image: Pixelated in web view (report manager)]

This is the same thing exported to PDF. It is somewhat better in PDF:

[image: PDF export of blurry report]

Here is a very similar report with chart in main report:

[image: Report Manager, similar report not as subreport]

And a very clear PDF export of the same:

[image: PDF export of clearer one]

I've tinkered with the dpiX/dpiY setting for PDF export which do improve the PDF export, but embedded images get shrunk. I've made the sub-report report size exactly the same size as the sub-report control of the parent report and played with explicit sizing as opposed to automatic sizing of the components of the chart.

Any recommendations on how to clear up this pixelation issue.

This is running on SSRS 2016 SP1 CU2.

Comment: What is your zoom level at in browser and in report?

Comment: It is noticeable at 100% and obviously worsened by higher zoom.

Comment: Not quite done, but in testing, I've found that rebuilding the chart in the new version of SSRS seems to resolve this issue. This report was moved from SSRS 2014 to 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rebuild the chart.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit old, but since I as of today was looking for, and found an answer to this question that is a bit more detailed I thought I should share it here.

See link below.

(Should there be a problem with the link:

Change the Chart background color in one of two ways:

1. Via the property window, set the Chart property (Not Chart Area) BackgroundColor to an actual value
2. Via right click on the chart (Not Chart Area), Set the Chart Property Fill to an actual value

Note, just to be clear:

Don't set `No Color` in either case above, if necessary set the same as the report background, it matters for the result.

When this is done, Antialiasing is enabled and lines are drawn much smoother)

[Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc8c40d1-3ee1-4a43-84c9-9820521bab9c/ssrs-line-chart-anti-aliasing-needed?forum=sqlreportingservices) to where I found the answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have not personally confirmed since I haven't seen the issue in quite some time, but this makes sense.